# Android App crashed with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: [Ljava/nio/file/LinkOption;

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, proguard

I'm getting the following exception after running my app with `minifyEnabled true`. But if I comment it out, the app opens just fine.

## Error

```
AndroidRuntime             E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: my.app.android, PID: 24808
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: [Ljava/nio/file/LinkOption;
    at af.h.<clinit>(JavaFlexibleTypeDeserializer.kt:18)
    at pl.h.onCreate(MyApp.java:302)
    at my.app.android.MyBaseApp.onCreate(MyBaseApp.kt:1)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.nio.file.LinkOption" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.app.android-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/my.app.android-2/lib/x86, /data/app/my.app.android-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at af.h.<clinit>(JavaFlexibleTypeDeserializer.kt:18) 
    at pl.h.onCreate(MyApp.java:302) 
    at my.app.android.MyBaseApp.onCreate(MyBaseApp.kt:1) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.file.LinkOption
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

## Investigations

### Keeping Classes in Proguard

I have already tried these lines in my proguard file, but was not able to fix the issue.

```
-keep class java.nio.file.** { *; }

-keep class java.nio.file.LinkOption { *; }

-keepclassmembers class java.nio.file.* {
    <fields>;
    <init>();
    <methods>;
}
```

### Updating Firebase Versions

I have tried updating Firebase to the latest version since earlier stacktrace shows a line from `FirebaseInitProvider` but the error `Failed resolution of: [Ljava/nio/file/LinkOption;` still show. It was changed into the stacktrace above after I updated the `classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14"`

### Desugaring

I have tried Desugaring with Java 11 `nio` based from: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java11-default-support-table using `coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs_nio:2.0.1'` but ran into a different issue where FakeDependency.jar is empty. Here's the stack overflow link to this issue: [Android Desugaring with nio Failed to transform FakeDependency.jar to match attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76362103/android-desugaring-with-nio-failed-to-transform-fakedependency-jar-to-match-attr)

But Desugaring with `coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.1'` build the project just fine, but still has `LinkOption` stacktrace seen above.

## Environments

This issue only exist when I build the app and install on an Android device at **API Level 23** with `minifyEnabled true`. But running it on an API Level 33 is just fine.

Below is a table of the different API Level with `minifyEnabled` setting and their status after running the installed app.

```
| API Lvl | minifyEnabled | Status    |
| ------- | ------------- | --------- |
|      23 | true          | Crashed   |
|      23 | false         | Succeeded |
|      24 | true          | Crashed   |
|      24 | false         | Succeeded |
|      33 | true          | Succeeded |
|      33 | false         | Succeeded |
```

I will be testing with API Levels 25, 26, and 27, and update the table above.

---

Any thoughts on what I might have missed or failed to do?

Comment: The class `java.nio.file.LinkOption` is not part of the app but of the Android API, thus you can not keep it. Not that the class is only available on API 26+ thus you have to set your minSDK to 26 to be able to use this class. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/LinkOption as you don't use the nio desugaring version this class is missing.

Comment: @Robert I find it weird that it's only crashing when it's obfuscated, but it doesn't crash when I set `minifyEnabled false`. The app is working on the previous version, but this new version fails. I've also added new dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a gradle build tools version issue.

On our previous release, we were using this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
    ...
}
```

But on our latest release, we were using this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2"
    ...
}
```

We are reverting back to `7.0.2` to work around this issue for lower API versions.

I am still not sure why this is, I will have to investigate. But if you have any information. Please do comment.