# Android Desugaring with nio Failed to transform FakeDependency.jar to match attributes

Tags: android, gradle, jdk-desugaring

Added the desugaring dependency as instructed in these links:

- https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java11-nio-support-table
- https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring

I have added these in my app's `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring "com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs_nio:2.0.1"
}
```

## Error

When I build the app, I'm getting these errors:

The entire build logs can be found here: https://pastebin.com/weKPjZ6E

Below is a trimmed down build logs.

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 115 ms

> Configure project :app
Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.
ComposeOptions.kotlinCompilerVersion is deprecated. Compose now uses the kotlin compiler defined in your buildscript.
Warning: 'kapt.use.worker.api' is deprecated and scheduled to be removed in Kotlin 1.8 release.

By default Kapt plugin is using Gradle workers to run annotation processing. Running annotation processing
directly in the Kotlin compiler is deprecated.

> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A build operation failed.
    Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration21'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration21'.
Failed to transform FakeDependency.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal-d8-desugar-methods, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
Execution failed for D8BackportedMethodsGenerator: C:\Users\User1\.gradle\android\FakeDependency.jar.
Cannot invoke "com.android.tools.r8.internal.GV.a(com.android.tools.r8.Diagnostic)" because "<parameter3>" is null

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: A build operation failed.
    Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration21'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration21'.
Failed to transform FakeDependency.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal-d8-desugar-methods, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
Execution failed for D8BackportedMethodsGenerator: C:\Users\User1\.gradle\android\FakeDependency.jar.
Cannot invoke "com.android.tools.r8.internal.GV.a(com.android.tools.r8.Diagnostic)" because "<parameter3>" is null
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:412)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
org.gradle.internal.operations.MultipleBuildOperationFailures: A build operation failed.
    Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration21'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.run(DefaultBuildController.java:142)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.run(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:55)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction$MyBuildController.run(ProjectImportAction.java:696)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration21'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1524)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$3700(DefaultConfiguration.java:159)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$DefaultResolutionHost.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:2174)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:1496)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:375)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection$UnresolvedItemsCollector.visitContents(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:372)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:284)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.getFiles(AbstractFileCollection.java:129)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Failed to transform FakeDependency.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal-d8-desugar-methods, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformingAsyncArtifactListener$TransformedArtifact.lambda$visit$2(TransformingAsyncArtifactListener.java:232)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Execution failed for D8BackportedMethodsGenerator: C:\Users\User1\.gradle\android\FakeDependency.jar.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$1.lambda$mapResult$3(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:159)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.mapFailure(Try.java:273)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.android.tools.r8.internal.GV.a(com.android.tools.r8.Diagnostic)" because "<parameter3>" is null
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Vg.a(R8_4.0.52_5a340ca2823c7e792fe09805c75f749b9d398d230bc0518bb54ae9b6b50addbe:39)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Vg.a(R8_4.0.52_5a340ca2823c7e792fe09805c75f749b9d398d230bc0518bb54ae9b6b50addbe:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.BackportedMethodListCommand$Builder.build(R8_4.0.52_5a340ca2823c7e792fe09805c75f749b9d398d230bc0518bb54ae9b6b50addbe:36)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DesugaredMethodsGenerator.generate(D8DesugaredMethodsGenerator.kt:43)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator.transform(DesugarLibUtils.kt:369)
    ... 111 more



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

---

Any thoughts how I could work around this issue?

## Update - 2023/Jun/2

I did not proceed into fixing this issue as my main issue was fixed. Below is a link to my main issue: [Android App crashed with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: [Ljava/nio/file/LinkOption;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76343712/android-app-crashed-with-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of)

Comment: I did not proceed into fixing this issue as my main issue was resolved. Which is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76343712/android-app-crashed-with-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of